# SQL Server Cursors and Group By

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I need to use a cursor with Group by statement based on group number from my table:
The current code I have gives me each record lets say for group 1 separately, which I do not want, I want the data to be retrieved grouped by.

```
DECLARE hello CURSOR
    FOR 

SELECT bygpno, SUM(bycash)
    FROM sheet1 
    GROUP BY bygpno
    ORDER BY bygpno


OPEN hello
FETCH NEXT FROM hello

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

FETCH NEXT FROM hello

END
    CLOSE hello
    DEALLOCATE hello
```

When I run the above it retrieves one line at a time in the result, which I do not know why.

Comment: Could you add some sample data and what - when you run your query - doesn't agree with your desired result?

Comment: If you just run the query and do not use a cursor, does that get you what you want? ie..e just run `SELECT bygpno, SUM(bycash) FROM sheet1     GROUP BY bygpno ORDER BY bygpno`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need a nested cursor so the outside one goes through the values of bygpno for each group and then within the loop you have another cursor loop that goes through the individual records

It'll look a bit like this

```
FETCH NEXT FROM hello INTO @bygpno, @Sum_bycash

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE CURSOR helloagain FOR SELECT ...,bycash FROM sheet1 WHERE bygpno = @bygpno
    OPEN CURSOR helloagain 
    FETCH NEXT FROM helloagain INTO ...,@bycash 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
        FETCH NEXT FROM helloagain INTO ...,@bycash 
        END
    CLOSE CURSOR helloagain 
    DEALLOCATE CURSOR helloagain 


    FETCH NEXT FROM hello INTO @bygpno, @Sum_bycash
END
```